# Why `tokio::main` can be used directly without any import?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have wrote the following code, and it can be compiled successfully,

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

}
```

But I'm curiously about why the `main` proc_macro can be used directly without any prelude or explicit use statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `tokio::main` is a full path, you can use `std::collections::HashMap` the same way for example.

All a `use` statement does is bring the object you use into scope, but the crates themselves are brought into scope automatically by `cargo`.

With earlier versions of Rust you'd have to write `extern crate tokio;` and the likes, but that's mostly a thing of the past.

Note that you do still have to add `tokio` to your `Cargo.toml`