# Spawning asynchronous task with a variable reference and exiting the root method "prematurely"

Tags: asynchronous, rust, memory, reference, borrow-checker

I'm trying to understand how ownership and borrowing work in Rust. I read that if you define a variable within a scope, and exit that scope, the variable is dropped. So let's say you define a variable within a method, and return a reference to that variable, that code would be uncompilable. This is explained in the Rust book:

```
fn main() {
    let reference_to_nothing = dangle();
}

fn dangle() -> &String {
    let s = String::from("hello");

    &s
}
```

However, in the asynchronous case. Let's say we create a variable and pass it by reference to a spawned task. Then we exit the method from whence it came, shouldn't that drop the variable? However, building the following code is possible, and the printout is valid:

```
use tokio;
use std::time::Duration;

async fn f2(x: &i32) {
    // Sleep for half a second within f2.
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await;

    // Attempt to read the reference to x.
    println!("[2]: f2: x = {}", x);
}

async fn f1() {
    let x = 42;

    // Spawn an asynchronous task that calls f2 with a reference to x.
    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        f2(&x).await;
    });

    println!("[1]: f1: x = {}", x);

    // No waiting for the spawned task to complete.
    // f1 can exit before f2 runs to completion.
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    f1().await;

    println!("[3]");

    // Sleep for a while to give f2 a chance to run.
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;

    println!("[4]");
}
```

Printout:

```
[1]: f1: x = 42
[3]
[2]: f2: x = 42
[4]
```

I expected the compiler to stop the code from building. But at the same time I would also think that it's a bit complicated for a compiler to understand every asynchronous use case that could cause memory issues. But I would at least expect the code to fail when running it, saying that "x" is out of scope or something. But maybe it works by chance, i.e., because the memory location where x is located wasn't wiped clean, but still contains the value 42? I'm obviously new to Rust and I'm not a very experienced programmer by any means.

Comment: nit: `use tokio;` does nothing but to verify `tokio` is available you [don't need to add that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77020210/why-tokiomain-can-be-used-directly-without-any-import/77020355#77020355).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the variable `x` to the new task by reference, you annotated the asynchronous block with the `move` keyword which means all free variables (those which are not defined within the block) are *moved* into the future.

You can still access the original `x` because `i32` implements `Copy` which means that a move instead of invalidating the old variable, just copies the data, so there are two versions of `x` the one inside of the task and the one in `f1`.

You can get the expected error by actually passing `x` by reference, either by ommiting `move` which results in this error:

```
error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `x`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:15:31
   |
15 |       let handle = tokio::spawn(async {
   |  _______________________________^
16 | |         f2(&x).await;
   | |             - `x` is borrowed here
17 | |     });
   | |_____^ may outlive borrowed value `x`
   |
   = note: async blocks are not executed immediately and must either take a reference or ownership of outside variables they use
help: to force the async block to take ownership of `x` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
15 |     let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
   |                                     ++++
```

or by taking the reference outside and moving that:

```rust
//…
    let x_ref = &x;
    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        f2(x_ref).await;
    });
//…
```

resulting in the error you expected:

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:17
   |
12 |       let x = 42;
   |           - binding `x` declared here
...
15 |       let x_ref = &x;
   |                   ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
16 |       let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
   |  __________________-
17 | |         f2(x_ref).await;
18 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'static`
...
24 |   }
   |   - `x` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Aside from a compiler or library bug it's actually impossible for Rust code which doesn't have any `unsafe` blocks to

> works by chance, i.e., because the memory location where x is located wasn't wiped clean, but still contains the value 42

Comment: I see. However, if that's the case, how would I go about passing any variable as reference to asynchronous functions, if they don't live long enough?

Comment: You can't pass a reference that can become invalid while you can still access it, avoiding such bugs is like most of Rusts selling points.